# Let A' be obtained from A by gauss' reduction; what can we say about their determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, divisibility

I’m currently in my first year of studies (mathematics); today while the professor was explaining Binet’s Theorem and its consequences i thought the following:

Let $A'\in M_n(K)$ be the matrix obtained as a result from reducing some $A\in M_n(K)$;
is it always true that $\det A|\det A'$?

It seems almost trivial to me given the multi-linear and alternating nature of the determinant (which I believe to have understood) but I’m not completely sure.

Comment: They will be multiples of each other, yes. That's not very useful though since any two nonzero elements of a field are multiples of one another. We can do a bit better, you can express $\det A'$ explicitly in terms of $\det A$. If your row reduction process involved scaling rows by scalars $\lambda_i$ at various different stages, $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ (we ignore the other row operations) then $\det A'=\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots\lambda_n\cdot\det A$

Comment: What do you mean by $a|b$ when $a,b$ are elements of an arbitrary field $K$, or is $K$ supposed to be a ring?